# Getting a MongoPoolClosedError with Mongoose & NodeJs

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, connection

I´m constanty getting this error, and i can´t close my connection properly. I used to have an async function, but it doesn´t make any difference.

Here´s the error:

```
MongoPoolClosedError: Attempted to check out a connection from closed connection pool
    at ConnectionPool.processWaitQueue (C:\Proyectos\SinergiaCRM\sinergiaDA\SinergiaDA\eda\sda_api\node_modules\mongodb\src\cmap\connection_pool.ts:757:37)
    at ConnectionPool.close (C:\Proyectos\SinergiaCRM\sinergiaDA\SinergiaDA\eda\sda_api\node_modules\mongodb\src\cmap\connection_pool.ts:509:10)
    at Server.destroy (C:\Proyectos\SinergiaCRM\sinergiaDA\SinergiaDA\eda\sda_api\node_modules\mongodb\src\sdam\server.ts:264:17)
    at destroyServer (C:\Proyectos\SinergiaCRM\sinergiaDA\SinergiaDA\eda\sda_api\node_modules\mongodb\src\sdam\topology.ts:773:10)
    at node:internal/util:375:7
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at destroyServer (node:internal/util:361:12)
    at C:\Proyectos\SinergiaCRM\sinergiaDA\SinergiaDA\eda\sda_api\node_modules\mongodb\src\sdam\topology.ts:506:38
    at Function.from (<anonymous>)
    at Topology.close (C:\Proyectos\SinergiaCRM\sinergiaDA\SinergiaDA\eda\sda_api\node_modules\mongodb\src\sdam\topology.ts:505:36)
```

Here is my connect/disconnect methods:

```
public mongoEdaConnect(req: Request)  {  
    mongoose.set('strictQuery', false)
    let con = this.connector(req).mongodb
    mongoose.connect(con, {})
        .then(() => console.log("conectado a mongo"))
        .catch(err => console.log(err)) 
  }
```

```
 public mongoEdaDisconnect() {
    mongoose.disconnect().then(()=> console.log("Desconectado de mongo"))
  }
```

this is how i call the class:

```
const mongoConnector = new Connections()
    
    try {
      mongoConnector.mongoEdaConnect(req)
    } catch (err) {
      if (err) throw err
      console.log("no conectado")
    }
```

```
 mongoConnector.mongoEdaDisconnect()
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

I tried calling it async methods, but got same result.
If i flag the disconnect method, the server keeps running, but i defenitly need to clse the connection in order to use a cloned website running on the same server.